# Laravel and Vue On Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, hosting

I have uploaded my vue and laravel application on shared hosting on Namecheap. Everything is working fine but when I make any change in vue files. They don't show up. I know it needs npm commands to compile and I tried installing npm in through ssh in the terminal but it gives me an error.

[image]

What should I do to make the changes in my vue files? I tried talking to the host but they said it can only be done by installing a node.js application first but I don't know if that will let my laravel run.
Will I have to make changes from local and reuploading all files again and again? or there are some specific files that can be reuploaded?
Thank you...

Comment: IMHO, you shouldnt be compiling your resources. like your vue templates, in production at all. Instead you should build the app as part of your deployment process and then put the fully built app on the production server.

Comment: If your project is set up correctly, you should just be able to run "npm run production" which will build the resources right away, without any additional modules and so on. if for some reason your hosting does not have node installed, I suggest switching to some other option (IMO DigitalOcean).